# Allow a HTML file which requires external files to be used in Electron

Tags: html, electron

How would you make this HTML file use the css file while being run in electron?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>First electron html app</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">`